# Dynamic link opening Play Store instead of Installed app

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-dynamic-links, react-native-firebase

Dynamic link is not opening the installed mobile app. It opens the Play Store instead. I have a button on my website on click of which, I want to open my app. For this, I am opening a dynamic link on click of that button on my website. When I click on the button, in some web browsers, the dynamic link is redirecting to Google Play store app(with my app on the Play Store) and in some browsers, opening Play Store website(with my app on the Play Store) inside the browser. However, when I send that dynamic link in the chat apps like Whatsapp and click on that link from the chat, then its opening my installed application.

I have also uploaded the release and debug SHA-256 keys from my local machine and the Google Play Store on the Firebase Console.

I have gone through several Github issues and stackoverflow questions, but could not find any solution for it.

#### Mobile

On mobile side, I have dynamic link listeners setup. We are generating the dynamic link on the backend side(code included below).

```
useEffect(() => {
    getInitialDynamicLink();
    const unsubscribe = dynamicLinks().onLink(handleDynamicLink);
    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);

const handleDynamicLink = link => {
  if (link?.url) {
    console.log('shared url is: ', link?.url);
  }
};

const getInitialDynamicLink = () => {
    dynamicLinks()
      .getInitialLink()
      .then(link => {
        handleDynamicLink(link);
      });
};
```

#### Backend

On the backend, I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-dynamic-links/v/1.0.0 to generate dynamic links.

[image: Backend Code]

#### package.json:

```
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^16.4.0",
"@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links": "^16.4.0",
"react-native": "0.67.4",
```

#### android/build.gradle

```
ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
        ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
        kotlin_version = "1.4.0"
        googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "19.2.0"
}
```

#### AndroidManifest.xml:

As mentioned in the doc https://developer.android.com/training/app-links#android-app-links, my app also has the App Link

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
      <data android:host="appname.page.link" android:scheme="https"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: were you able to figure this out ?

Comment: No. I ended up using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-branch

Comment: Thanks for the provided library, I will give it a try.